# Seize your future

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, translation-check, motto

What would "Seize your future/the future" be in Latin? I've got Carpe futurum, but my latin is quite poor.

I want to use it as a motto for an educational company. I want to use it as it echos the motivational associations of carpe diem, but is intended as an imploration to students that they must seize the reigns of their future, and become the makers of their destiny.

I'd greatly appreciate feedback/help with the translation.

Answer (score 5):

*Carpe futurum* is certainly one way of saying what you want to say.

You could equally well say *carpe futura* ("seize the future [things]") using the neuter plural, or *carpe futuras* (sc. *dies*), i.e. "seize the future [days]" (in this case, I'd make *dies* out to be feminine, as it refers to a point of time).

Instead of *carpe* you could also use *cape* (the imperative of *capio* rather than *carpo*).

Instead of *futurum* you could also use another expression to give the meaning "your future", such as *fortunam* ("your luck/fate") or *sortem* ("your fate").

Or you could use the image of reins that you employed in your question and say ***frenos cape fortunae*** ("seize the reins of your fate").

Comment: I think you mean frenos instead of renos.

Comment: @cnread Indeed!